# Showing Image icons for datatable default button tools

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am new to jquery datatables. Right now using datatable tabletool for export table data into excel and pdf. datatable library provides images folder where there are respective image for each export action is available, e.g image for excel and image for pdf so forth.

In `datatable.css` file there was one block that was mentioning that remove these comment to show image buttons. I did but its not working.

Any Help please...

Here is my code.

```
dg_table = $('#dg_table').dataTable({
//      "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span12'T><'span6'l>fr>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "assets/data-tables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [ "copy", "xls","print" ]
        },
});
```